# Axios POST request is not working properly for django-allauth social login?

Tags: django, axios, httprequest, django-allauth

**MY PROBLEM**

I have two endpoints **/api/google/login** and **/api/ms/login** both are using [django allauth social login](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html). when I try to give a POST request to both of the endpoints using **Axios** it gives me 401 Unauthorized. I am using [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) to get the access-token.

**Here is the code -**

```
axios.post('/api/google/login', {access_token: 'my_access_token'})
.then(res => {here_my_response_block_is_handlled})
.catch(err = {here_my_error_block_is_handlled})
```

But when I directly use my link from browser and copy-paste the same access_token here and post it successfully process the request and return back me token.

**Here is the direct API URL access view of Django endpoint**

[image: django_all_auth_social_login]

**What I Have Done**

1. I have checked the **request** from the **browsers's network tab** when I give **POST request** from **frontend** and it is sending the **request payload** correctly with the same key pair of **access_token**.
2. I am getting the access_token correctly from **react-google-login** because I **console.log** it and use the same access_token when I am sending the request from direct API link showed in the image above.
3. My backend is working well and the proof is the image above. This process is working fine.